# How to support i18N of the TITLE of docusaurus

Tags: docusaurus

Docusaurus supports I18N.

- For page, I can create md/mx under the folder `118n/{language}/docusaurus-plugin-content-docs/current`
- For react component, I can use react hook `useDocusaurusContext`, like this

  ```
  const { i18n } = useDocusaurusContext();
  return (
     <div>{i18n.currentLocale === "zh" ? "高兴" : "Happy"}</div>
  );
  ```
- However, I don't know how to handle the title and tagline declared in `docusaurus.config.js`

  ```js
  const config = {
      title: "MyTitle", ❶
      tagline: "Subtitle", ❷
      ...
      i18n: {
          defaultLocale: 'en',
          locales: ['en', 'zh'],
      },
      ...
  };
  ```

  How to let ❶ and ❷ support I18N?

I know how to resolve it

[image]

However, this solution is too ugly, any better solution?